# TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException. "I'm trying to pause my game after the game over."

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

**I'm trying to pause my game after the game over. For that, I raised `raise'Game Over!'` in my `game_over()` function under `class Game_Snake2` and used try and except in `run()` function under the same class. But unfortunately I'm getting TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException. I can't figure out what did I messed up! Help me to get rid of it. Thanks in advance.**
*My code is here:*

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.math import Vector2
from pathlib import *

cell_size = 40
cell_number = 19
screen_color = (175, 215, 70)
snake_color = (183, 111, 122)
food_color = (70, 70, 214)
score_color = (56, 76, 11)
score_bg_color = (167, 211, 65)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((cell_number * cell_size, cell_number * cell_size))
base_directory = Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
apple_path = 'snake2_resources/images/apple.png'
apple = pygame.image.load(base_directory / apple_path).convert_alpha()
font_path = base_directory / 'snake2_resources/font/poetsen_one_regular.ttf'
game_font = pygame.font.Font(font_path, 24)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Snake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.snake_body = [Vector2(5, 10),Vector2(4, 10),Vector2(3, 10)]
        self.direction = Vector2(0, 0)
        self.new_body = False
        snake_path = base_directory / 'snake2_resources/images/snake'

        self.head_up = pygame.image.load(snake_path / 'head_up.png').convert_alpha()
        self.head_down = pygame.image.load(snake_path / 'head_down.png').convert_alpha()
        self.head_right = pygame.image.load(snake_path / 'head_right.png').convert_alpha()
        self.head_left = pygame.image.load(snake_path / 'head_left.png').convert_alpha()
        
        self.tail_up = pygame.image.load(snake_path / 'tail_up.png').convert_alpha()
        self.tail_down = pygame.image.load(snake_path / 'tail_down.png').convert_alpha()
        self.tail_right = pygame.image.load(snake_path / 'tail_right.png').convert_alpha()
        self.tail_left = pygame.image.load(snake_path / 'tail_left.png').convert_alpha()
        
        self.body_vertical = pygame.image.load(snake_path / 'body_vertical.png').convert_alpha()
        self.body_horizontal = pygame.image.load(snake_path / 'body_horizontal.png').convert_alpha()
        
        self.body_tr = pygame.image.load(snake_path / 'body_tr.png').convert_alpha()
        self.body_tl = pygame.image.load(snake_path / 'body_tl.png').convert_alpha()
        self.body_br = pygame.image.load(snake_path / 'body_br.png').convert_alpha()
        self.body_bl = pygame.image.load(snake_path / 'body_bl.png').convert_alpha()

    def update_snake_head(self):
        head_direction = self.snake_body[1] - self.snake_body[0]

        if head_direction == Vector2(1, 0):
            self.head = self.head_left
        elif head_direction == Vector2(-1, 0):
            self.head = self.head_right
        elif head_direction == Vector2(0, 1):
            self.head = self.head_up
        elif head_direction == Vector2(0, -1):
            self.head = self.head_down

    def update_snake_tail(self):
        tail_direction = self.snake_body[-2] - self.snake_body[-1]

        if tail_direction == Vector2(1, 0):
            self.tail = self.tail_left
        elif tail_direction == Vector2(-1, 0):
            self.tail = self.tail_right
        elif tail_direction == Vector2(0, 1):
            self.tail = self.tail_up
        elif tail_direction == Vector2(0, -1):
            self.tail = self.tail_down
    
    def draw_snake(self):
        self.update_snake_head()
        self.update_snake_tail()

        for index, body_part in enumerate(self.snake_body):
            body_part_x = body_part.x * cell_size
            body_part_y = body_part.y * cell_size
            body_part_surface = pygame.Rect(body_part_x, body_part_y, cell_size, cell_size)
            
            if index == 0:
                screen.blit(self.head, body_part_surface)

            elif index == len(self.snake_body) - 1:
                screen.blit(self.tail, body_part_surface)

            else:
                previous_body_part = self.snake_body[index + 1] - body_part
                next_body_part = self.snake_body[index - 1] - body_part

                if previous_body_part.x == next_body_part.x:
                    screen.blit(self.body_vertical, body_part_surface)

                elif previous_body_part.y == next_body_part.y:
                    screen.blit(self.body_horizontal, body_part_surface)

                else:
                    if previous_body_part.x == -1 and next_body_part.y == -1 or previous_body_part.y == -1 and next_body_part.x == -1:
                        screen.blit(self.body_tl, body_part_surface)

                    elif previous_body_part.x == -1 and next_body_part.y == 1 or previous_body_part.y == 1 and next_body_part.x == -1:
                        screen.blit(self.body_bl, body_part_surface)

                    elif previous_body_part.x == 1 and next_body_part.y == -1 or previous_body_part.y == -1 and next_body_part.x == 1:
                        screen.blit(self.body_tr, body_part_surface)
                    
                    elif previous_body_part.x == 1 and next_body_part.y == 1 or previous_body_part.y == 1 and next_body_part.x == 1:
                        screen.blit(self.body_br, body_part_surface)

    def add_body(self):
        self.new_body = True
    
    def move_snake(self):
        if self.new_body == True:
            snake_body_copy = self.snake_body[:]
            snake_body_copy.insert(0, snake_body_copy[0] + self.direction)
            self.snake_body = snake_body_copy[:]
            self.new_body = False
    
        else:
            snake_body_copy = self.snake_body[: -1]
            snake_body_copy.insert(0, snake_body_copy[0] + self.direction)
            self.snake_body = snake_body_copy[:]

    def reset(self):
        self.snake_body = [Vector2(5, 10), Vector2(4, 10), Vector2(3, 10)]
        self.direction = Vector2(0, 0)

class Food:
    def __init__(self):
        self.randomize()

    def draw_food(self):
        food_surface = pygame.Rect(self.position.x * cell_size, self.position.y * cell_size, cell_size, cell_size)
        screen.blit(apple, food_surface)

    def randomize(self):
        self.food_x = random.randint(0, cell_number - 1)
        self.food_y = random.randint(0, cell_number - 1)
        self.position = Vector2(self.food_x, self.food_y)

class Game_Snake2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_update = pygame.USEREVENT
        pygame.time.set_timer(self.screen_update, 156)
        self.snake = Snake()
        self.food = Food()
        self.pause = False

    def draw_grass(self):
        grass_color = (167, 209, 61)
        
        for row in range(cell_number):
            if row % 2 == 0:
                for column in range(cell_number):
                    if column % 2 == 0:
                        grass_surface = pygame.Rect(column * cell_size, row * cell_size, cell_size, cell_size)
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen, grass_color, grass_surface)

            else:
                for column in range(cell_number):
                    if column % 2 != 0:
                        grass_surface = pygame.Rect(column * cell_size, row * cell_size, cell_size, cell_size)
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen, grass_color, grass_surface)
    
    def display_score(self):
        score = str(len(self.snake.snake_body) - 3)
        score_surface = game_font.render(score, True, score_color)
        score_x = cell_size * cell_number - 60
        score_y = cell_size * cell_number - 40
        score_shape = score_surface.get_rect(center=(score_x, score_y))
        score_apple = apple.get_rect(midright = (score_shape.left, score_shape.centery))
        score_background = pygame.Rect(score_apple.left, score_apple.top, score_apple.width + score_shape.width + 6, score_apple.height)
        
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, score_bg_color, score_background)
        screen.blit(score_surface, score_shape)
        screen.blit(apple, score_apple)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, score_color, score_background, 2)
    
    def draw_elements(self):
        self.draw_grass()
        self.snake.draw_snake()
        self.food.draw_food()
        self.display_score()
    
    def play_sound(self, sound_name):
        sound_path = base_directory / f'snake2_resources/sounds/{sound_name}.mp3'
        sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(sound_path)
        sound.play()
    
    def is_hit(self):
        if self.food.position == self.snake.snake_body[0]:
            self.food.randomize()
            self.snake.add_body()
            self.play_sound('ding')

        for body_part in self.snake.snake_body[1:]:
            if body_part == self.food.position:
                self.food.randomize()

    def game_over(self):
        if not 0 <= self.snake.snake_body[0].x < cell_number or not 0 <= self.snake.snake_body[0].y < cell_number:
            self.play_sound('crash')
            raise 'Game Over!'
            # self.snake.reset()

        for tail in self.snake.snake_body[1:]:
            if tail == self.snake.snake_body[0]:
                raise 'Game Over!'
                # self.snake.reset()

    def update_screen(self):
        self.snake.move_snake()
        self.is_hit()
        self.game_over()
    
    def run(self):
        running = True
        
        while running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
                    
                    if event.key == K_RETURN:
                        # pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
                        self.pause = False
                        self.snake.reset()
                    
                    if not self.pause:
                        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                            if game.snake.direction.y != 1:
                                game.snake.direction = Vector2(0, -1)

                        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                            if game.snake.direction.y != -1:
                                game.snake.direction = Vector2(0, 1)

                        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                            if game.snake.direction.x != 1:
                                game.snake.direction = Vector2(-1, 0)

                        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                            if game.snake.direction.x != -1:
                                game.snake.direction = Vector2(1, 0)
            
                elif event.type == self.screen_update:
                    self.update_screen()
                
                elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

                try:
                    if not self.pause and event.type == self.screen_update:
                        self.update_screen()

                except Exception:
                    self.display_score()
                    self.pause = True

            screen.fill(screen_color)
            self.draw_elements()
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game_Snake2()
    game.run()
```

*I'm getting this error:*

```
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.4)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\archive_root\CSE\Python\portfolio_py\projects_py\games_py\snake2_py\snake_game2.py", line 271, in <module>
    game.run()
  File "e:\archive_root\CSE\Python\portfolio_py\projects_py\games_py\snake2_py\snake_game2.py", line 250, in run     
    self.update_screen()
  File "e:\archive_root\CSE\Python\portfolio_py\projects_py\games_py\snake2_py\snake_game2.py", line 215, in update_screen
    self.game_over()
  File "e:\archive_root\CSE\Python\portfolio_py\projects_py\games_py\snake2_py\snake_game2.py", line 209, in game_over
    raise 'Game Over!'
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.  You post 250 lines and appear to require testing input -- this is excessive for the problem you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `str` you need to `raise` a specific type of exception, for example

```
raise RuntimeError('Game Over!')
```

You can either use one of the [built-in exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#concrete-exceptions) or you can define your own by inheriting from the appropriate base class.

Comment: I tried with - raise Exception('Game Over!')

same error bro.

Comment: @ZamaaN That will not produce a `TypeError` like your original example, that version will work fine

Comment: what exactly do i need to use here? I'm new with exception.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `raise` a `string` as an Exception, you must pass an exception instance or class. Or as mentioned in the official python [tutorial on errors](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

> The sole argument to raise indicates the exception to be raised. This
> must be either an exception instance or an exception class (a class
> that derives from Exception).

So you must either use an existing Exception class, say RuntimeError like @Cory Kramer explained in his answer.

or create your own Exception class.

```
class GameOverException(Exception):
    pass
```

and call it

```
raise GameOverException('Game Over!')
```

Comment: what would be inside the class? or will it be left blank?

Comment: For your purpose the class would be a dummy class. You just have to put the keyword `pass` inside the class.

Comment: "e:\archive_root\CSE\Python\portfolio_py\projects_py\games_py\snake2_py\snake_game2.py", line 212, in game_over
    raise GameOverException('Game Over!')
__main__.GameOverException: Game Over!

Comment: maybe i need to think without exception. new way to pause and restart after pressing Enter.

Comment: When you raise an exception, an "error" is thrown, that is how exceptions work. Please read more about exceptions and exception handling. And choose it as the answer if it solved the question you asked, so people who look for the same issue in the future can find it.